# How to perform action only once per item in an array (SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I have an array that holds 2 different SwiftUI view types (soon to be 6 different types) that I need to iterate an action only once over. They are different types of dice for tabletop RPGs (D4, D6, D20, etc) that each have a function within the struct of the views to display a random number within a Text field. The issue I'm running into is that I have a button that should trigger those functions once per view, but instead it sets the same number on all of the views.
The relevant code is below, please note any [...] are where I've condensed code that isn't relevant. Thank you!

Here is the struct for the D6DiceView, it contains the function for the random roll (this is the full current view)

```
struct D6DiceView: View {

    @Binding var rolledValue: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle (cornerRadius: 10)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text(rolledValue)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }

    func d6rollButtonPressed() {
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1..<7)
        rolledValue = "\(randomInt)"
        print("Random number is \(randomInt)")
    }
}
```

This is the "main" view where all the dice would be held/
I'm only trying to get the D6DiceView working, but there will be multiple different dice views after this is working.

Here is the array and initial value for each die

```
struct DiceSelectView: View {
    @State var viewArray = [] as [Any]
    @State var initialRolledValue = "1"
    ...
}
```

Here is where the views are displayed

```
LazyHGrid (rows: selectedDiceColumns)  {
    ForEach(0..<viewArray.count, id: \.self) { index in
        if self.viewArray[index] is D4DiceView {
            D4DiceView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        self.viewArray.remove(at:index)
                        print("D4 tapped")
                    }
                }
        } else {
            D6DiceView(rolledValue: $initialRolledValue)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        self.viewArray.remove(at:index)
                        print("D6 tapped")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the button that is pressed to trigger the dice roll

```
VStack {
    Button(action: rollButtonPressed, label: {
        Text("Roll Dice")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
            .background(Color(.systemIndigo))
            .cornerRadius(10)
    })
}
```

Here is the function that actions on the button press, "rolling" just the D6DiceViews

```
func rollButtonPressed() {
    let d6Array = viewArray.compactMap {$0 as? D6DiceView}

    d6Array.forEach { item in
        item.d6rollButtonPressed()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't post links to GitHub. Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your code and paste it directly in the question.

Comment: @pawello2222 Updated, thank you!

Comment: Is the problem that the display of the numbers is all the same or that all the random numbers are the same? Can you provide the output that happens when you press the button?

Also, you might make things easier on yourself if you use a little bit of OOP and create a base DiceView class that has a roll() function.  Then you can avoid all the type checks that you do and just iterate over all the views and call roll() on them.

Comment: SwiftUI Views are struct values, so your `rollButtonPressed` just calls a function for view copies. You need to rethink concept - operate with models in view model and view should  depend on view model to refresh on changes.

Comment: @asperi I think I figured out a better method, I do have other questions but I relate them in a new post.